# Unable to upload file when using JQuery file upload, Spring MVC and Spring Security.

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jquery-file-upload

I am implementing a simple website for image upload. Frameworks in use are 
[jQuery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) 
Spring MVC 
Spring Security

I've implemented a form and a controller for file upload but when trying to read files, files seems to be unavailable. 
I've struggled with the Security `_csrf` for a while but I've figured it out. 
Now when I try to read files no files can be read when reaching the controller.
here is the source code 
https://gist.github.com/AdelinGhanaem/f67b311cda7aa9efe83c

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging and checking Spring Security/MVC architecture this is what I've came up with:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<UploadPictureResult> pictureUpload(FirewalledRequest initialRequest) {
     DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest request = (DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest) initialRequest.getRequest();

    try {
        MultipartFile multipartFile  = request.getFile("files[]");
        List<MultipartFile> multipartFileList = request.getFiles("files[]");

        Iterator<String> iterator = request.getFileNames();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            MultipartFile file = request.getFile(iterator.next());
            service.save(toImage(file));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<UploadPictureResult>(new UploadPictureResult(),
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<UploadPictureResult>(new UploadPictureResult(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Notice the FirewallRequest !!!**